# Trouble understanding Python decorator code

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to learn about Python decorators. The guide I'm going through referenced this code:

```
from time import sleep


def sleep_decorator(function):

    """
    Limits how fast the function is
    called.
    """

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        sleep(2)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@sleep_decorator
def print_number(num):
    return num

print(print_number(222))

for num in range(1, 6):
    print(print_number(num))
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, `@sleep_decorator` essentially runs `sleep_decorator(print_number(num))`. What I'm struggling to understand is how the print function and for loop below that fits into the whole thing. Are these all also part of the decorator? Or is the `@sleep_decorator` redefining `print_number` so that it always runs through the `sleep_decorator` function?

Comment: Your last suggestion is the correct one. And no, what it essentially runs is `sleep_decorator(the_undecorated_print_number)(num)`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you; the link was helpful was well. Could you explain a little more on the separated (num) component? Why is that not included in under the print_number function?